# Find button using associated text in selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have button details like below.

```
<button type="button" class="add-to-cart button primary-button false item-action-button">
          Add to Cart
        </button>
```

And xpath is `/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/button`

How do I click on the button?

I tried using this `find_element_by_xpath('/button[contains(text(), "Add to Cart")]')`

But it doesn't work. I don't want to just do .click() on given xpath. Is there way to click by finding text?

I am automating using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **/**  **Selects from the root node**
>
> **//** **Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection doesn't matter where they are**
>
> find_element_by_xpath('/button[contains(text(), "Add to Cart")]')

Since you are selecting from current node use

```
find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Add to Cart")]')
```

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if there are any issues

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(' Add to Cart')
link.click()
```

if still it does not works then go to the source of page you will see a Iframe you need to first switch into it